# ¿Cómo acceder a valores de JSON?

Tags: c#, json, jsonobject

Tengo un Json que que al deserializarlo viene de la siguiente forma, cuando lo veo en mi visual studio se ve de la siguiente manera:

¿Cómo puedo acceder a cada una de esas listas, después que he deserializado al modelo que describo abajo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría insertar este modelo en otro que me permita recorrer cada clase que lo integra como si fuera una lista.

```
public class Root
{
public List<Clase1> {get;set;}
public List<Clase2> {get;set;}
}
public class Clase1
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class Clase2
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Qué versión de .net utilizas? Si es netCore, puedes utilizar el [JsonSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) que ya viene en el `namespace System.Text.Json;`. Si no es .netCore/Net5/Net6, puedes utilizar Newtonsoft, como han sugerido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ási me funciono: Deserializando en un Diccionario.

```
 public async Task<Dictionary<string, List<object>>> 
GetDataPatagoniaAsync(string clientToken, string url)
            {
                var respuesta = string.Empty;
                var result = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("clientToken", clientToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<object>>>(respuesta);
                }
    
                return result;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola una de las librerias mas polulares es newtonsoft json serialize.

Tambien para facilitar el trabajo del deserializado es usar vectores vetor[], en vez de listas.

Si agregas la libreria linq, puedes manipular los vectores como listas.

Comment: Y si preguntamos qué versión de .Net usa? No tiene sentido utilizar Newtonsoft si está usando NetCore.